# Notepad++ switching between documents mid-editing

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I have an issue with Notepad++ that makes using it a total sore.

Essentially, Notepad++ will just switch between documents WHILE I am entering text. So before I know it, I am continuing a sentence in a completely unrelated document that was also open at the same time.

I suspect it has something to do with documents being updated by Windows in the background and Notepad++ reloading them, but not sure.  I may actually see a highlighted dropdown while typing that I then unententionally select but it is displayed so shortly (in between two key entries) that I cannot make out what it says. Maybe on the other hand, that dropdown is just the auto - complete, so it something else, maybe some key combination that I enter?

The only workaround is to have only one document open at a single time so there is nothing to switch to, but this is not a workable solution.

Any ideas what this can be?

PS Version: 7.4.2, Windows 32 bit on Windows 10.

Comment: May be you're typing Ctrl + [digit] that gives focus to [digit]th tab

Comment: no, I am experiencing it now as well, I am really just entering text... e.g. the word "documentation" just made me enter "ntation" in the other document

Comment: @Rusty75 – maybe you can check that *File status auto-detection* is set correctly in menu *Settings* > *Preferences*.

Comment: hi @miroxlav, thanks for the reply - it was however the touch-sensitive tracking stick in the keyboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason - my laptop had a touch-sensitive 'joystick' in the middle of the keyboard so whenever I accidentally touched it while typing, all sorts of unforeseen stuff happened..